# How i can use helium in angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, helium

I'm trying to use Helium to discovery css class that is not in use.

My index.html:

```
<script type="text/javascript" 
    src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/helium-css/1.1/helium.min.js" 
    async 
    onload="helium.init()">
</script>
```

When i paste in the textarea the links of the pages, example:

```
http://localhost:4200/login
```

i receive in my console:

> Cannot read property 'sort' of undefined

Someone using helium in angular? thanks

Comment: Try removing async

Comment: if i remove async the textarea don't appear

Comment: Your `onload` method is running after the script has loaded, but before the DOM is ready.  It should be in the document load event, not the scripts load event.

Answer (score 0):

1. Load without script without async
2. Remove onload
3. Place the < script> on the bottom of the page, followed by
   4.

   < script type="text/javascript">                 window.addEventListener('load',function(){               helium.init();  }, false); < /script>

Comment: In the bottom of my head, body index or in the bottom of my component html?

Comment: @hiLorena It shouldn't matter.